# Как правильно дописать фрагментированный tcp пакет?

Tags: c#, асинхронность, .net, сокет

Здравствуйте.

Есть некое серверное приложение, данные принимаются асинхронно, размер принимаемых пакетов известен. Иногда пакеты приходят кусками, в таком случае делается повтор чтения из сокета, например, размер пакета 1994 байт, пришел кусок 1360 байт, осталось получить 634 байта, делаю проверку `socket.Available > 0` и что я вижу, что данных нет `(socket.Available = 0)`, делаю чтение нового пакета и приходит оставшаяся часть пакета? Как быть? Может, стоит не делать такую проверку, а просто дописывать оставшуюся часть?

```
private void EndRecieveQ0(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        Socket handler = this.StateConnection.workSocket;
        if (CheckSocketConnected() == false)
            return;
        int recievedBytes;
        try
        {
            recievedBytes = this.StateConnection.workSocket.EndReceive(result);
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes += recievedBytes;
        if (this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes == this.StateConnection.ExpectedPacketLength)
        {
            byte[] response = new byte[0];
            bool termination;
            new PacketHandler(this, this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer, out response, out termination);
            this.StateConnection.termination = termination;

            Array.Resize(ref this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer, response.Length);
            this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer = response;
            this.StateConnection.ClientSendBytes = 0;
            sendDone.Reset();
            this.StateConnection.workSocket.BeginSend(this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer, 0, this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
            sendDone.WaitOne();
        }
        else
        {
            this.StateConnection.LeftToReceiveLength = (this.StateConnection.ExpectedPacketLength) - this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes;

            if (handler.Available > 0)
            {
                receiveDone.Reset();
                this.StateConnection.workSocket.BeginReceive(
                    this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer,
                    this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes,
                    this.StateConnection.LeftToReceiveLength,
                    SocketFlags.None,
                    EndRecieveQ0,
                    null);

                receiveDone.WaitOne(); //?
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.BufferPacketLog("[<-] " + "\n" + "handler.Available = " + handler.Available.ToString(), this.ID, 3);
                this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer = new byte[10];
                receiveDone.Reset();
                this.StateConnection.workSocket.BeginReceive(
                    this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer, 
                    0, 
                    this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer.Length, 
                    0,
                    NewPacketHeader, 
                    null);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is SocketException)
        {
            closeDone.Reset();
            termination(this.StateConnection.ID);
            closeDone.WaitOne();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и мешанина. 

Вы бы как-то структурировали свой "проект", да и описали хотя бы слегка все эти ReceiveDone, closeDone и т.п.  
(а то ведь о логике выполнения можно только догадываться).

Comment: нет здесь никакой мешанины, логика почти абсолютно четкая, вопрос ясно расписан, тем, кто знает, что такое Socket.BeginReceive и Socket.EndReceive не составит труда его прочитать. Причину я выяснил, данные приходят позже, на данный момент поставил в место, где выясняется что handler.Available не > 0

this.Connection.sleepcount = 0;
while (handler.Available == 0 && this.StateConnection.sleepcount < 30)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    this.Connection.sleepcount++;
}

за некоторое время данные приходят и handler.Available становится > 0, после этого можно спокойно дописывать

Answer (score 1):

`handler.Available` показывает только тот факт, что в буфере сетевой карты остались еще какие-то данные к данному приложению, полагаться на этот факт бессмыссленно.

То, что у вас в `if (handler.Available > 0)` вам нужно оставить, а то, что в `else` перенести в конец `if (this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes == this.StateConnection.ExpectedPacketLength)`

Также, `ManualResetEvent`ы `receiveDone` и `sendDone` вам не нужны

```
private void EndRecieveQ0(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        Socket handler = this.StateConnection.workSocket;
        if (CheckSocketConnected() == false)
            return;
        int recievedBytes;
        try
        {
            recievedBytes = this.StateConnection.workSocket.EndReceive(result);
            //receiveDone.Set();
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes += recievedBytes;
        if (this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes == this.StateConnection.ExpectedPacketLength)
        {
            byte[] response = new byte[0];
            bool termination;
            new PacketHandler(this, this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer, out response, out termination);
            this.StateConnection.termination = termination;

            Array.Resize(ref this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer, response.Length);
            this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer = response;
            this.StateConnection.ClientSendBytes = 0;
            //sendDone.Reset();
            this.StateConnection.workSocket.BeginSend(this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer, 0, this.StateConnection.ClientSendBuffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
            //sendDone.WaitOne();

            // vvvvv Начинаем читать новый пакет
            this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer = new byte[10];
            //receiveDone.Reset();
            this.StateConnection.workSocket.BeginReceive(
                this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer, 
                0, 
                this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer.Length, 
                0,
                NewPacketHeader, 
                null);
            //receiveDone.WaitOne();
            // ^^^^^
        }
        else
        {
            // vvvvv Продолжаем читать предыдущий пакет
            this.StateConnection.LeftToReceiveLength = (this.StateConnection.ExpectedPacketLength) - this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes;

            this.StateConnection.workSocket.BeginReceive(
                this.StateConnection.ClientReceiveBuffer,
                this.StateConnection.ClientReceivedBytes,
                this.StateConnection.LeftToReceiveLength,
                SocketFlags.None,
                EndRecieveQ0,
                null);
            // ^^^^^
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is SocketException)
        {
            //closeDone.Reset();
            termination(this.StateConnection.ID);
            //closeDone.WaitOne();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Не требуется проверять доступность данных в сокете перед чтением из него - все методы чтения умеют дожидаться прибытия данных. Если пришло мало данных - просто вызовите BeginReceive еще раз.

PS какую версию .NET Framework вы используете? Если 4.5+, то советую открыть для себя async и await.